# How to filter by content url in CQWP

Tags: 2010, filter, content-query-web-part

I'm looking to filter items in a Content Query Webpart by URL, e.g. URL contains this particular string. URL is not available in the list of fields though. Specifying 'FilterField1="URL"' in the source code also does not work. Adding URL to CommonViewFields makes no difference.

My WebPart points to a Document library with mostly doc files and images.
Is there a way to do this using the WebPart filter?

I know I could conceivably filter in xslt (because the URL is available here), but it would be slower, plus I need the top 10 items that match the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The CQWP is already setup with this ablity. When setting up your filters in the web part, select the column you are filtering on and then input "[PageQueryString:Param1]" putting your parameter in place of Param1.

See image below for example, I am filtering based on the Account and have "?Account='NameOfAccount'" in the URL.

[image: CQWP Additional Filters Options]

Comment: This is not what I need. I need to filter by the url of the items being loaded in the CQWP. E.g. all items the url of which contains ".xlsx" .

Comment: Then I'd maybe try using the Content Search of Search Results web part. You can use the path filter